# Save HTTP API JSON data in ORACLE DB

Tags: java, json, oracle

Is there any way I can create a stored procedure or function in my Oracle 11g, that fetches the JSON data from my HTTP API (Example Data : https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/ggplot2/commits) and saves in my table in Oracle? Or can I do it from my Java Application?